# Why does my function not return anything to the App Display?

Tags: api, flutter, asynchronous, dart

I'm trying to make my first little API project, where all book reviews and book titles of stephen king should display on screen through the new york times api.

I tried to create a Future and return the Card to the App Display but nothing shows up. While printing the results works well. But I can't see anything on screen. I just want a card where all results are shown, just like in the console. (for the moment, at least)

I show you the complete code:

````
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark(),
      home: BookReview(),
    );
  }
}

//outsource the class BookReview for OOP
class BookReview extends StatelessWidget {
  List<int> bookNum = [
    0,
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4,
    5,
    6,
    7,
    8,
    9,
    10,
    11,
    12,
    13,
    14,
    15,
    16,
    17,
    18,
    19,
    20,
    21,
    22,
    23,
    24,
    25,
    26,
    27,
    28,
    29,
    30,
    31,
    32,
    33,
    34,
    35,
    36,
    37,
    38,
    39,
    40,
    41,
    42,
    43,
    44,
    45,
    46,
    47,
    48,
    49,
    50,
    51,
    52,
    53,
    54,
    55,
    56,
    57,
    58,
    59,
    60,
    61,
    62,
    63,
    64,
    65
  ];

  static const apiKey = 'jH8F2A1FCudwGV8udVAU4YSLLEr8vqxT';
  static const apiURL =
      'https://api.nytimes.com/svc/books/v3/reviews.json?author=Stephen+King&api-key=$apiKey';

  Future<Card> getBookData() async {
    String bookTitle;
    String reviewURL;

    http.Response response = await http.get(apiURL);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var decodedData = jsonDecode(response.body);

      //TODO make an array with the number of results and save the value into a variable
      //highest array number is 65 so there are 66 results at the end
      for (int book in bookNum) {
        String bookTitle = decodedData['results'][book]['book_title'];
        String reviewURL = decodedData['results'][book]['url'];

        print(bookTitle + ' ' + reviewURL);
      }
      return Card(
          color: Colors.red,
          child: Column(
            children: [Text(bookTitle + reviewURL)],
          ));
    } else {
      print(response.statusCode);
      throw ('there is an error with the status code');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Stephen King NYT Reviews'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          FlatButton(
            onPressed: () {
              getBookData();
            },
            child: Icon(
              Icons.picture_as_pdf,
              size: 50.0,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```
````

Comment: Pro tip: Replace your bookNum declaration with `var bookNum = List.generate(66, (i) => i);`

Answer (score 0):

your widget `BookReview`  is Stateless so when the first time created ... not change After that ...

**now You Have 2 way ....**

**first** change your widget to stateFull and call SetState() After getting Date ...

**second way** still use stateless widget and use Future Builder ...
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html

---

*****First Way Example*****
https://dartpad.dev/7de589d386edba57472efba02e90c4c3
this code not working on dartpad because used http library.please copy this into your project.

the class MyResponses created with this Site ...
https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/

Comment: @cyberpVnk please add your code ... i try to correct it ...

Comment: I did in the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I changed to stateful and also setState but nothing happens. No Card appears.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark(),
      home: BookReview(),
    );
  }
}

//outsource the class BookReview for OOP
class BookReview extends StatefulWidget {
  static const apiKey = 'jH8F2A1FCudwGV8udVAU4YSLLEr8vqxT';
  static const apiURL =
      'https://api.nytimes.com/svc/books/v3/reviews.json?author=Stephen+King&api-key=$apiKey';

  @override
  _BookReviewState createState() => _BookReviewState();
}

class _BookReviewState extends State<BookReview> {
  Card bookCard;

  var bookNum = List.generate(66, (i) => i);

  Future<Card> getBookData() async {
    String bookTitle;
    String reviewURL;

    http.Response response = await http.get(BookReview.apiURL);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var decodedData = jsonDecode(response.body);

      //TODO make an array with the number of results and save the value into a variable
      //highest array number is 65 so there are 66 results at the end
      for (int book in bookNum) {
        String bookTitle = decodedData['results'][book]['book_title'];
        String reviewURL = decodedData['results'][book]['url'];
      }
      print(bookTitle);
      print(reviewURL);

      return Card(
          color: Colors.red,
          child: Column(
            children: [Text(bookTitle + reviewURL)],
          ));
    } else {
      print(response.statusCode);
      throw ('there is an error with the status code');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Stephen King NYT Reviews'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          FlatButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              final Card tmpBookCard = await getBookData();
              setState(() {
                bookCard = tmpBookCard;
              });
            },
            child: Icon(
              Icons.picture_as_pdf,
              size: 50.0,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```